# apt-move says the packages are moved but they are gone

Tags: apt, repository, debian, localrepository

I'm trying to setup a Ubuntu mirror with selected packages from different repositories, by using `apt-move`, which I've been using on Ubuntu 10.04 without (too much) problems.

I've installed `apt-move` and setup it accordingly to my needs:

```
# dpkg -l | grep apt-move
ii  apt-move                    4.2.27-2                   Maintain Debian packages in a package pool
```

The configuration file `/etc/apt-move.conf` is as follows:

```
# cat /etc/apt-move.conf | grep -v -e ^# -e ^$
APTSITES="/all/"
LOCALDIR=/var/local/mirrors/ubuntu
DIST=precise
PKGTYPE=binary
FILECACHE=/var/cache/apt/archives
LISTSTATE=/var/lib/apt/lists
DELETE=no
MAXDELETE=20
COPYONLY=no
PKGCOMP="none gzip"
CONTENTS=yes
GPGKEY=
```

Of course, I've created the directory mentioned in `LOCALDIR`.

Let's try it. After doing a `sudo apt-get -d install vim` I have some debs laying around on `/var/cache/apt/archives`:

```
# ls -1 /var/cache/apt/archives/
libgpm2_1.20.4-4_amd64.deb
libpython2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
lock
partial
python2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
python2.7-minimal_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
vim_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
vim-common_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
vim-runtime_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_all.deb
vim-tiny_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
```

I first do a `apt-move get`.

```
# apt-move get

Updating from local Packages files...

All done, exiting.
```

Then a `apt-move move`:

```
# apt-move move

Moving files...
Skipping files:
Moving Files:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgpm2_1.20.4-4_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpython2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python2.7-minimal_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-common_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-runtime_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim-tiny_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb

All done, exiting.
```

So far so good. Let's check the repository pool.

```
# ls -lah /var/local/mirrors/ubuntu/pool/
total 8,0K
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4,0K dic  3 11:39 .
drwxr-sr-x 5 root staff 4,0K dic  3 11:39 ..
```

Oops. It's empty. So, where are the packages?

```
# find / -iname vim-common_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
#
```

Nowhere. Nice. The `dists` dir is empty, too:

```
# ls -lah /var/local/mirrors/ubuntu/dists
total 8,0K
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4,0K dic  3 11:50 .
drwxr-sr-x 5 root staff 4,0K dic  3 11:50 ..
```

However, there's a `.apt-move` directory with some information:

```
# ls /var/local/mirrors/ubuntu/.apt-move/
arch  binary  dists  pool  precise.arch.amd64  precise.binary  source  version
```

But there's not too much info in there, actually. The directories `dists` and `pool` are also empty.

Going more manual won't help. Using `apt-move movefile` results in the same:

```
# apt-move movefile vim_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb 

Moving files...

Skipping files:
Moving Files:
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb

All done, exiting.
```

Aaand empty directories. Some idea on what could be happening?

Am I doing something wrong?

Are there some alternatives to apt-move (that fit my needs here!) that are worth trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug on Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-move/+bug/946605). Fortunately, it [has been fixed on Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=692342) and installing the version 4.2.27-3 from Debian Sid just by downloading and installing the package with wget/dpkg seems to fix the problem.